# GUI Components in Gio and not in Gtk?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Why some GUI components are in `Gio` not in `Gtk`? E.g:
`GMenu`, `GMenuItem`.
I always thought that `GTK` is the place of the GUI components and `Gio` for in/out libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GMenu/GAction system is not a GUI component. It's a model for creating menus that can be exposed in a variety of different ways. For instance, GActions can be exposed to dbus and triggered by other processes. Or you can use libappindicator or a similar library to build a system tray icon around GMenus. GTK+ provides several controls that map GMenus to GUI elements like traditional menubars and pop-up menu buttons.